# Problemas Con mostrar una jsp en iframe con spring security y html5

Tags: html5, spring-security, iframe

Trato de incrustar esta url en mi iframe pero no aparece

```
<li><a href="<c:url value="./MisFinanzas.htm"/>"    
 target="ventana_iframe">Saldos</a></li>
```

Éste es mi iframe:

```
   <iframe   src="myIframe" name="ventana_iframe" scrolling="no" 
   height="700px" 
   width="101.3%"> </iframe>
```

Y ésta es la ruta de mi controlador:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/secured/adm/MisFinanzas.htm")
  public String adminsMisFinanzas() {
    return "foradmins/saldo";
  }
```

Comment: Cuando formateas código, asegúrate que dejes una línea vacía entre texto regular y el código, para que se respeta el formato.